# web user control adding items problem

Tags: c#, asp.net

On one web user control

```
public void displayFindingSection(int sectionsid,string text,string head)
{
   SectionHeading.Text = head;
   DataSet totImgs;
   totImgs = objGetBaseCase.GetFindingsNewerImages(sectionsid);
   FindingViewerlist.DataSource = totImgs;
   DataBind();
   SectionText.Text = text;
}
```

On other web user control

```
public void DisplayFindingsViewer(CipCaseWorkflowItem2 item)
{
  FindingViewerDisplay.Visible = true;
  ImageAndSimpleViewer.Visible = false;
  objGetBaseCase.GetFindingsImages((Convert.ToInt32(Session["CaseId"])), item.ItemId);
  FindingsViewerNew = objGetBaseCase.GetFindingViewerNewElementDetails(item.ItemId);

  for (int i = 0; i < FindingsViewerNew.Count; i++)
  { 

    FindingViwerDisplay uc =  (FindingViwerDisplay)LoadControl("FindingViwerDisplay.ascx");                 
 FindingPlaceholder.Controls.Add(uc);
  uc.displayFindingSection(Convert.ToInt32(FindingsViewerNew[i].Index), FindingsViewerNew[i].Text, FindingsViewerNew[i].Title);

   }
}
```

I am adding the all the image in user control and displaying the image, but when i am using the above code, web user control is also adding every time and one image is showing in in control **what i want is all images should show in only one user control**.. sectionsid is getting the image id from the database. I think prob with for loop but i am unable to solve it.. help me it that

Comment: FindingViwerDisplay uc =  (FindingViwerDisplay)LoadControl("FindingViwerDisplay.ascx"); Place it before the loop and check

Comment: i kept that, then only one image is showing not all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be it is happening u have defined it inside the loop

```
 FindingViwerDisplay uc =  (FindingViwerDisplay)LoadControl("FindingViwerDisplay.ascx");                 
 FindingPlaceholder.Controls.Add(uc);
```

On Each loop you are adding uc  and calling   displayFindingSection whcich ofcouse add 1 image than loop go back add a new control again and than add one image it will go on till your loop completion so add control once before loop and call just displayFindingSection  in loop..

Do this,

```
 FindingViwerDisplay uc =  (FindingViwerDisplay)LoadControl("FindingViwerDisplay.ascx");                 
 FindingPlaceholder.Controls.Add(uc);

//define here a dataTabel with three columns let say u have datatable dt
for (int i = 0; i < FindingsViewerNew.Count; i++)
 { 

 dt.Rows.Add(Convert.ToInt32(FindingsViewerNew[i].Index), FindingsViewerNew[i].Text,   FindingsViewerNew[i].Title);


 }
  uc.displayFindingSection(dt);
```

Then work out on that dt in displayFindingSection

Sorry if i am wrong...

Comment: I have done the same, i already used the same code, if am using ur code  then i am getting only, one image is showing in one user control, while i am having 2, 3 or more image in table and rest is not showing

Comment: Then pass the dataset totImgs in the parameter ..add all image souces in dataset in loop then pass it to displayFindingSection ..Might be it happening you are defining datasource each time and binding it which have only 1 image source..Is your control showing the last image you passed through loop???/

Comment: yes it is showing last image, can u plz let me syntax how to do.. which u are saying

Comment: My displayFindingSection is taking 3 argument (int sectionsid,string text,string head) then how could i use uc.displayFindingSection(dt); it will show error no overload for method takes '1' arguments

Comment: u have to change displayFindingSection is taking 3 argument (int sectionsid,string text,string head to one parameter that will take this dt and then u'll loop on dt in displayFindingSection and fill totImgs according to dt data and at the end u'll bind it ..Now i hope you get my point